# How to extend width of filter menu in KendoUI Grid

Tags: css, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, width

I use KendoUI Grid to show data. When I use **columns.filterable** in configurations guide, the display data is too long.

[image]

As you can see in the above picture.

And I investigated and used **.k-multicheck-wrap** to extend the width.

BUT the problem I met that css class above will affect to all filter menu.

[image]

SO I want to affect the Uploaded Time column **only**.

Comment: Show us what you did, if possible in a working demo at dojo.telerik.com, so we can suggest something..

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jquery and [filterMenuInit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit) event. This event is fired only once - when you click filter icon. And there you can do this magic.

```
filterMenuInit: function(e){
    if(e.field == "UploadedBy")
        {
            e.container.css({"width": "800px"});
        }
},
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/oMUHE/2)

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but I found this answer looking for a similar issue.  Subsequently, and worth noting, I also found that the filterMenu popup sizes itself to the content.  So if you have custom content in the filter, you can specify a width within that content and not need `filterMenuInit`.